# onListItemClick() show different-2 activities

Tags: android

I have responceid (String responceid = Activity2.getData()) for every row ...I want when I click on any position of list item it show its corresponding responceid ...so how to bind responseid for every row ....**responceid takes from database**

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String responceid = Activity2.getData();

    Object o = (String) (Notepadv3.this).getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    Toast.makeText(this, "this row  responce id is= " + " " + , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: _responceid_ or _responseid_?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used an adapter to fill the listView then use getItemId() to retrieve the database id.

- Salil